# OAuthSwift ではてなの OAuth を使うときに二重URLエンコードされないようにする正しい方法は?

Tags: swift, macos, oauth

OAuthSwift を使ってはてなの OAuth 認証を使おうとしています。OAuth の仕様に詳しい方に、この変更が正しいのか伺いたく思います。

[サンプルプロジェクト (GitHub)](https://github.com/Nyoho/HatenaBookmarkAPITest) を作って試したところ、最後のアクセストークンを取得するところで 401 で `oauth_problem=token_rejected` が返ってきてしまうエラーに悩まされていましたが、
OAuthSwift のソースを追いかけてみると、
`OauthSwifthClient.swift` の `makeRequest()` の中で最後の `request.headers` で `oauth_token=\"hogehoge%253D%253D\"` となっており、`oauth_verifier` も同様に `%253D` が含まれていました。

本来は `hogehoge%3D%3D` という文字列が post されなければならないのに '=' が2重にURLエンコードされているのです。

そこで、 `OAuthSwift/OAuth1Swift.swift` の `postOAuthAccessTokenWithRequestToken` の中でパラメタとして渡される `oauth_token` と `oauth_verifier` を、先に `.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` することで一旦 URL エンコードを解除するという[変更をしました (commit eca80d176725c25c4a36df8b6e775f48d35f405f)](https://github.com/Nyoho/OAuthSwift/commit/eca80d176725c25c4a36df8b6e775f48d35f405f)。
するとうまく OAuth 認証が通るようになりました。

OAuth の正しい方法として、この変更でよいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OAuth1 exchange fails due token secret being URL encoded. · Issue #140 · OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/issues/140)

おそらく上のIssueでの修正漏れですね。ここでの修正に従うなら `self.client.credential` の中身はURLエンコードされていない文字列になるべきですが、Authorization時のコールバックでクエリストリングをURLデコードせずに `self.client.credential` に格納してしまっているようです。

https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/blob/0.5.0/OAuthSwift/OAuth1Swift.swift#L54-L69

ですから `postOAuthAccessTokenWithRequestToken` までにURLデコードすること自体は間違っていませんが、前述のハンドラ関数の中でデコードしてから格納するようにした方がよいと思います。

（手元にSwiftの開発環境ないですし、IssueやPullRequestの投稿は遠慮しておきます）

Comment: ありがとうございます! ご回答にしたがってハンドラ関数の中でデコードするPRとissueを立てようと喜び勇んでいたところ、作者の @dongriat さんが見て下さったようで、そのように変更して下さいました。
https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift/commit/669f3c4b16564169029e016fafef2aa846df4837
はてなのサンプルも入れて下さいました。
感謝申し上げます。